# How to rotate multiple features from multiple layers at once in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need to rotate multiple lines and points from multiple layers at once. I want to rotate all points / lines as if they where a multipart feature.

Does someone know any solution in QGIS? I tried to select all layers with the vertex tool, I can move it, but I can't rotate it this way.  [image]

Comment: I dont understand. The differenct colored lines are different layers? How should they be rotated, around each lines centroid?

Comment: Yes exactly they are in different layers. To rotate them around the centroids sounds good. How can I do this? Basically I want to rotate this whole net of lines in once, because its so much work to rotate every single line.

Comment: What? I dont get it

Comment: Ah okay then number 2

Answer (score 2):

It the QGIS main menu click on "Processing" and then "Toolbox"  or (Ctrl+Alt+T). In the Processing Toolbox search-bar, type **Rotate**.  Click on the Rotate algorithm from the vector geometry group.  Near the bottom of the **Rotate** dialog box you will see the *Run as Batch Process...* button.  This will allow you to select multiple layers.  You may have to put in the anchor point in each layer but it should work.

Comment: Thank you this seem to work but one little problem remain. If I choose the batch processing, how can I set it to overwrite my input layers instead of create new ones?

Comment: furthermore it looks like you cant set to rotate only selected features in the batch processing window -.-

Comment: I think you may have to save the new layers.  It is "New" data points so overwriting your original data may be dangerous.  You can always export your layers and overwrite.  Make sure your original is backed up.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, rotating several selected features from different layers does not have a special tool in Qgis and must be done in several steps.  Considering the practicality of the above topic, the absence of this tool can be felt in the popular Qgis software.  It should be added in future versions.